# How to create object variable upon inheritance?

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance

I wish to create a variable `self._query` in class `Hello`, and:

- I wish the variable is created when class `Hello` is inherited by another class.
- I wish the variable is declared from within class `Hello` (and not from outside, with `Hello._query = ...`).
- I wish to declare it only once.

However, to me it seems I can only define this variable via the `__init__` method of `Hello`. Is there any other way, as this will not be executed when the class is being inherited?

This is what I have:

```
import mylib

class Hello(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Hello, self).__init__()
        self._query = mylib.Query()

    def say_hello(self):
        print self._query.hello()

    def say_goodbye(self):
        print self._query.goodbye()
```

The only workaround I can come up with is this, but this doesn't create `self._query`. Instead it results in global variable `_query`:

```
import mylib
_query = mylib.Query()

class Hello(object):

    def say_hello(self):
        print _query.hello()

    def say_goodbye(self):
        print _query.goodbye()
```

Is it possible to create `self._query` somehow, when `Hello` is being inherited, making `self._query` available within the `Hello` class?

Comment: You mean you want only a single instance of that to be available?

Comment: So you want a *class attribute*? Or are you trying to do something on class creation, which you can do with metaclasses? Could you give a less abstract example?

Comment: `Hello.__init__` is called by the inherited `__init__` with `super` like you did in your first example.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I was looking for a class attribute. Never crossed my mind to just define the variable directly after the class declaration. Works great. Thanks. If you like, create an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jonsharpe, I was looking to simply use class attributes.

```
import mylib

class Hello(object):
    _query = mylib.Query() # class attribute

    def say_hello(self):
        print self._query.hello()

    def say_goodbye(self):
        print self._query.goodbye()
```